# I'm having trouble with the .translate function in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

This is a silly repeating parrot program I wrote for practice. It worked on python 2.0, but it's not working now that I've started working with python 3.7. I keep getting this error...

```
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I'm not sure what is happening.

```
import time
from string import whitespace, punctuation


# This prints a string up to a certain number of times equaling the number of characters in the string.
print ("I'm a parrot! Teach me a phrase! SQUAK!"),
parrot = input()
count =  range(0, int(len(parrot.translate(None, punctuation).translate(None, whitespace))),
(int(len(parrot.translate(None, punctuation).translate(None, whitespace)))-(int(len(parrot.translate(None, punctuation).translate(None, whitespace))-1))))
for i in count:
    print ('SQUAK!'),
    print (parrot)
    time.sleep(1.5)

print ('That phrase had %s letters in it! SQUAK!') % len(parrot.translate(None, punctuation).translate(None, whitespace))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.translate` was changed between Python 2 and 3. In Python 2 the second argument to [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) contains characters that are to be removed from the input string. In Python 3 [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) does not accept a second argument, instead characters that map to `None` in the translation table are removed.

You should be able to do this in Python 3:

```
parrot.translate({ord(c): None for c in punctuation + whitespace})
```

to remove punctuation and whitespace characters. E.g.

```
>>> parrot = "I'm a parrot! Teach me a phrase! SQUAK!"
>>> parrot.translate({ord(c): None for c in punctuation + whitespace})
'ImaparrotTeachmeaphraseSQUAK'
```

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
import time
from string import whitespace, punctuation

print ("I'm a parrot! Teach me a phrase! SQUAK!"),
parrot = input()
translation_table = {ord(c): None for c in punctuation + whitespace}
cleaned_parrot = parrot.translate(translation_table)

for c in cleaned_parrot:
    print('SQUAK!', parrot)
    time.sleep(1.5)

print('That phrase had {} letters in it! SQUAK!'.format(len(cleaned_parrot)))
```

Comment: @NakorIsilani: what error? Are you talking about Python 2? You must implement it differently for each Python version.

Comment: Also note that you should be using `raw_input()` for Python 2.

Comment: No sorry. I'm in Python 3.7 I'm trying to remove the punctuation and whitespaces from the user input. The program asks for a phrase (This can be basically anything), and it repeats the string enough times to match the number of letters in the word or phrase, minus the punctuation and white spaces.

Comment: @NakorIsilaniL yes, I can se what your code is trying to do. Try doing what I have shown you in my sample code. You can't pass `None` to `translate()` in Python 3, you must pass a translation table.

Comment: Ok, so now I've got it returning my input string without whitespaces or punctuation. That's a start. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NakorIsilani: I've added a simplified and working Python 3 code to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It works! As you can see, the longer the phrase you teach the parrot, the more annoying it is. :) Thanks for your help. It's going to take me a while to learn all the changes from my 2.0 code to 3.0.